# Socket.io reverting to XHR / JSONP polling for no apparent reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I think Socket.IO should choose The best method to find connection with the server 
 in the series ,

> ```
>   Websocket , 
>   FlashSocket  
>   and then JSONP
> ```

but my server which is running socket.io 0.7.7 on the top of node 0.4.9 (on windows compiled with cygwin) goes to XHR/JsonP polling without any apparent reason. I have checked on all ports from 80 - 89 just to make sure , and the problem remains the same all the time.

I also checked for console logs in both the sides.
Firebug Gives No error just shows me the XHR get requests instead.

and On the Server Console it gives me :

```
   info - socket.io started
   debug - client authorised  // i dunno why this is occuring though
   info - handshake autorised 154845454664764
   setting request Get/socket.io/1/xhr-polling/154845454664764
   debug - setting poll timeout
```

.
.
. and so on
Any reason in mind guys ??

Comment: why you vote-down without reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be using a version of [Firefox that has WebSockets disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets).

> **Warning:** Among other things, a key reason WebSockets is currently
>   disabled by default in Firefox 4 and 5 is the discovery of a security
>   issue in the protocol's design. Using WebSockets in those versions of
>   Firefox in a production environment is not recommended at this time.
>   If you still wish to experiment with WebSockets, you may do so by
>   opening about:config and setting the network.websocket.enabled
>   preference to true. You will also need to set the
>   network.websocket.override-security-block preference to true in order
>   to allow initializing a WebSocket connection.

Comment: Well it should support flash socket right :P . flash sockets are there just as a transport option next to websocket

Comment: @Darkyen | oh yeah! that's right... uhm, is the flash `.swf` is present and accessible?

Comment: it windows so hell yeah but it dosnt gave me a policy file output

Comment: @freedompeace where should be it accessbile ? i have put it in all the places. ( directory of html , server directory everywhere still dosnt work)

Comment: @Darkyen, the file pointed at by `WEB_SOCKET_SWF_LOCATION` should be accessible via. HTTP from wherever you're trying to access it from. If you haven't set this variable up, set it up, because socket.io depends on it.

Comment: @freedompeace okay lets try that.. can u come to the javascript chat please ? i need help

Comment: @freedompeace can u exactly specify me , maybe a code sample on how to setup socket.io to use flash if Websocket are NOT availible

Comment: @Darkyen Sorry, I was on the train. I'll put up a sample for you as soon as I get home.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FPDew/ Well that isn't very much of a sample, but you'll hopefully get the point.

Comment: @Darkyen let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1989/discussion-between-freedompeace-and-darkyen)

Comment: Discussion moved to chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1989/discussion-between-freedompeace-and-darkyen

Answer (score 1):

Firefox does have websockets disabled. Standard socket.io does not have flashsocket so you have to add it to your [configuration](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO) =>

```
io.set('transports', [                     // enable all transports (optional if you want flashsocket)
    'websocket'
  , 'flashsocket'
  , 'htmlfile'
  , 'xhr-polling'
  , 'jsonp-polling'
]);
```

Then it should work just fine.

---

```
debug - client authorised  // i dunno why this is occuring though
```

socket.io can do [authorization](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing).

Comment: thank you ^_^ i had to move it to a linux VM though to make things work , i think windows compiled version must be having issues with win7 "ENHANCED" security propaganda