# Speeding up Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, socket.io

When I listen for a client connection in Socket.IO, there seems to be a latency of 8-9 seconds as it falls back to XHR. This is too slow for most purposes, as I'm using Socket.IO to push data to users' news feeds, and a lot can happen 8 or 9 seconds.

Is there any way to speed up this failure?

**EDIT**:

After deploying to Nodejitsu's VPS I tried this again and the socket connection was nearly immediate (enough that a user wouldn't notice). I'm only experiencing this on my local machine. So the question may actually be: why is it so slow on my local machine?

Comment: what setup does your local machine have?

Answer (score 0):

This question is almost impossible to answer without more information on your local setup, but it's interesting that you're failing over to XHR. The following question *might* explain why it's failing over to XHR, but not if you're able to use the same browser successfully once it's published.

[Socket.io reverting to XHR / JSONP polling for no apparent reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881742/socket-io-reverting-to-xhr-jsonp-polling-without-no-apparent-reason)

Another potential problem I've read about is that your browser has cached the incorrect transport method. You could try clearing your browser cache and reconnect to see if that gets around the problem.

https://groups.google.com/group/socket_io/browse_thread/thread/e6397e89efcdbcb7/a3ce764803726804

Lastly, if you're unable to figure out why it's not going using WebSockets or FlashSockets,  you could try removing them as options from your socket.io configuration so that when you're developing locally, you may be able to get past that delay for quicker development at least.